# Add additional References when compliling code at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, codedom, system.diagnostics, json.net

I found this program ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655 ) where i compile the code during runtime, It works for code that uses the reference,

```
using System;
```

Following is the the code for the program that compiles code during runtime,

```
        CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();

        string Output = "Out.exe";
        Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

        textBox2.Text = "";
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
        CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                            "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                            ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                            ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Successful Compile
            textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            textBox2.Text = "Success!";
            //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
            if (ButtonObject.Text == "Run") Process.Start(Output);
        }
```

And Following is the code i need to compile at runtime,

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    namespace Tsubame
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"url");

                // Create Client
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                // Assign Credentials
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

                //Grab Data
                var data = client.DownloadString(@"url");

                JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
                string getFristRow = Convert.ToString(o["Body"][0]["RowId"]);

                string encaplulateStart = "\\\"";
                string encaplulateEnd = "\\\":";

                List<string> _matches = new List<string>();
                _matches = Regex.Matches(getFristRow, @"(?<=" + encaplulateStart + ").*(?=" + encaplulateEnd + ")")
                                    .Cast<Match>()
                                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                                    .ToList();

                foreach (string head in _matches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(head);

                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I input this gives the error code,

```
    Error Number: CS0234
```

For the references other than System. May I please know how to add additional references during runtime so that it can compile sucessfully :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the references in `CompilerParameters` using [`CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies.aspx):

```
var parameters = CompilerParameters
{
    GenerateExecutable = true,
    OutputAssembly = Output,
    ReferencedAssemblies = {
        "System.dll",
        "System.Core.dll",
        // etc
    }
};
```

(Of course you don't have to use object initializer syntax to set this up, but it makes it neater IMO.)

Comment: i used lyk
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
is there a difference of this and your method?? thanx :) and the var parameter stub gives errors when try it on the code, is there any reason?? please forgive if its a simple solution but i am new to this side programming :)